# Angular child to parent communication using service

Tags: angular

I have seen in various places that show communication between parent to child component using Input, Service and template variables.

If I want to communicate from child to parent component we can use Output Emitters.

Is there a way to communicate using a service from child to parent component?
The problem is if we have two clone components for eg :

in parent.component.ts

```
<child-component></child-component>
<child-component></child-component>
```

using emitters we can use callback function for each emitter as below

```
<child-component (someevent) = "callback1($event)"></child-component>
<child-component (someevent) = "callback2($event)"></child-component>
```

Using service how can we design the same as what emitters do?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple and a good idea when you need to share data between not just children and parent but also siblings. BehvaiorSubject to the rescue:

Your service

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    dataSrc$ = new BehaviorSubject('default data');

  changeData(data) {
    this.dataSrc$.next(data);
  }
}
```

Child component

```
@Component(...)
export class ChildComponent {
    data: any;

  constructor(private dataSvc: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSvc(data => {
        this.data = data // do whatever you want with it
    })
  }

  sendToParent(data) {
    this.dataSvc.changeData(data);
  }
}
```

Parent component

```
@Component(...)
export class ParentComponent {
    data: any;

  constructor(private dataSvc: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSvc(data => {
        this.data = data // do whatever you want with it
    })
  }

  sendToChild(data) {
    this.dataSvc.changeData(data);
  }
}
```

Obviously come up with better names for your methods but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: How can you distinguish which data is from which child if we have two instances of child component basically a clone ?

Comment: can you give a real life example where you'd want to have two identical child components?

Comment: also, if it's just two, you might be better off with the EventEmitter (the version you posted), just pass the id of the child as a second parameter into one callback, rather than having two callbacks

Comment: A real life example would be
   <abstract-component> some content</abstract-component>
 <abstract-component>some other contentt</abstract-component>

Comment: well, that's not exactly a real life example :D

Answer (score 0):

Using a service, you should subscribe to your service's Observable once into your parent's code, and you have to put something into the event you `.next()` from the children, so you are able to identify which child emitted the event.